# How to write a particular formula in form of google script code

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write the attached formula as google script language. I don't have the knowledge to do so. Some one Please help me to write this as a google script in the comment below.

```
=FILTER(B9:Z32,D9:D32>=(Bookings!$E12-14),F9:F32<=(Bookings!$BH12+14))
```

This is my current status-

```
function FilterRng(){
var sheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Data");
var range= sheet.getRange(9,2,29,25);
var value= range.getValue();
var newRange= sheet.grtRange(9,35,29,25);
var condition1= Bookings!$E12-14;
var condition2= Bookings!$BH12+14;


if (D9:D32>=(Bookings!$E12-14)&(F9:F32<=(Bookings!$BH12+14)){
newRange.setValue(value);
}
}
```

it will be great if anyone can help with this

Comment: Hi! Since this has nothing to do with Excel or Excel VBA, I've removed those tags. But I've added the [tag:google-apps-script] tag, since GAS isn't *quite* JavaScript (or at least, not modern JavaScript -- it's basically ES3 plus some bits of ES5).

Comment: So what's the problem? Please edit your question and include description of the issue you're experiencing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Where are you stuck? What does your code do/not do that you don't/do want?

Comment: @T.J V8 is coming to apps script. Wait for it....

Comment: @I'-'I - I've always wondered why it was taking so long... :-)

Comment: @I'-'I - Sorry, I'm not seeing the relevance...? (And I *think* it was multiple vendors, not just Google, but would have to go digging to be sure... Ancient history now, we're talking 2006-2009.)

Comment: @I'-'I will v8 bring any ease to non coders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**????**

I tried to figure out what your doing but I couldn't get all of it.  You have a lot of things wrong.  Have you tried any examples in the documentation?  That might be a good starting point for you.

I think this is close to what you want but I'm not sure what you wish to do once you satisfy the conditions because what your doing makes no sense to me.

```
function FilterRng(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var cond1=ss.getSheetByName('Bookings').getRange('E12').getValue() - 14;
  var cond2=ss.getSheetByName('Bookings').getRange('BH12').getValue() + 14;
  var valA1=sh.getRange('D9:D32').getValues();
  var valA2=sh.getRange('F9:F32').getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<valA1.length;i++){
    if(valA1[i][0]>=cond1 && valA2[i][0]<=cond2){
      //you want to do something but I'm not sure what  
      //perhaps sh.getRange('Some Cell').setFormula('some cell formula')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Also give me some idea, the rows will keep on growing, that is, the row number 32 will keep on increasing so is there any way i can keep it dynamic?

Comment: Cooper, inside the if loop (if the condition is met) i want to copy data from B9 to Z32 to AI9 to BG32.
Please tell me how to do that.